# jQuery and executing code until mouseout is called

Tags: jquery, events, hover, mouseover, mouseout

Good day all, I am tasked with building a slider for our site. Here is my goal:

```
<div id="abc">
  <div id="slider">...</div>
</div>
```

I need to move "slider" left 30px at a time when a button is hovered over, and right 30px when another button is hovered over.

My problem is that there doesn't seem to be a reliable method for telling the code that the mouse hasn't left the are in question, unless there is something I did not think about or read yet. In other words, when the mouse is OVER the a button, the code to move "slider" left is executed until the mouseout is called. I'm not really sure how to do this.

**The only way I can think of is** to look at the offsetTop and offsetLeft and offsetTop DOM properties and compare them to the mouse position, than run checks to see if the mouse is within the bounds of the box, and if not than it will stop the execution of code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly easy.

```
var timerID;
$("#left").hover(function() {
  timerID = setInterval(slideLeft, 1000);
}, function() {
  clearInterval(timerID);
});

function slideLeft() {
  $("#slider").animate({left: -30});
}
```

and similar for right.

You only need to use `hover()` if there's something you need to stop when the mouse leaves the area. Otherwise you can simply use the `mouseover()` event.

**Note:** the actual effect I've put in there probably isn't right but it depends entirely on the slider plugin you're using. Adjust as required.

Comment: thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't sure if I could clearInterval outside of the function that it was called in, but when I look up the documentation for JavaScript, it does say "ID=setInterval()" and that makes it all clear now. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to check where the mouse is, as the `mouseout` event will be triggered when the mouse leaves the element.

To make the movement repeat while the mouse is hovering the element, start an interval that you stop when the mouse leaves the element:

```
$(function(){

  var moveInterval;

  $('#moveLeft').hover(function(){
    moveInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
      // here you move the slider
    }, 100);
  }, function(){
    window.clearInterval(moveInterval);
  });

});
```

Comment: thanks so much, I gave the answer to @cletus because I believe he was first to post answer. I think the last post is the first one, but i'm not sure. If it is the other way around, I'd be happy to change it. Thanks to the both of you.

Comment: @Tomaszewski: You can't tell from the order they are displayed which answer was posted first. They are shown in random order specifically to reduce the importance of posting first in favour of the quality of the posts. If you reload a page a few times you will see answers with the same score switching place (except the accepted answer which is always shown first). If you hover the approximate time indication you will see the exact time, and it shows that cletus did in fact post his answer first.